# What is the best strategy for implementing sub-modules in Python so that only the ones the end-user uses are loaded?

Tags: python, lazy-loading, python-module

What is the best strategy for implementing sub-modules in Python so that only the ones the end-user uses are loaded?

I did check and there are many questions and answers on this topic but I couldn't find any that specifically outline or recommend a way to make only the sub-modules specifically requested by the user get imported.

I clearly do not understand the specific mechanics of modules.  But so far I've been using `__init__.py` and it seems to load all the sub-modules, especially ones I import in it.  So references to materials which clearly present the intended functions and strategies for loading modules would be educational (Thank you.)

For example say I build a module that creates specific types of Sequences but has several flavors.  Just as an example, maybe FixedSequence is abstract base class and FixedList, FixedByteArray and FixedArray are implemented subclasses (flavors) but likely only one or 2 of these is needed.  How would I set up the top module to make everything available but not load them if someone does a "import fixedsequences".  Where the module structure is...

```
./fixedsequences
  ./fixedsequences/__init__.py
  ./fixedsequences/fixedsequence.py
  ./fixedsequences/fixedlist.py
  ./fixedsequences/fixedbytearray.py
  ./fixedsequences/fixedarray.py
```

and the `./fixedsequences/__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from .fixedsequence import FixedSequence
from .fixedlist import FixedList
from .fixedbytearray import FixedByteArray
from .fixedarray import FixedArray
```

Am I wrong in assuming that all the imports in the `__init__.py` cause all modules to be loaded?  I have to assume yes.

So, if I want those sub-modules to be loadable but not loaded unless the user specifically imports them or references them by attribute name from the base module, or one of the sub-modules does.

Best strategies, educational material of best module and package structures welcome.

Comment: You would have to remove the imports from your `__init__.py` and users of your package would then have to import those modules using the full path `from fixedsequences.fixedsequence import FixedSequence` instead of `from fixedsequences import FixedSequence`. You cannot (reasonably) conditionally import only the sub modules dynamically

Comment: @IainShelvington yeah, and I realize I didn't mention part of my question includes how to make nice clean modules such that extraneous support variables, outside modules and functions are not exposed in each module.  Because originally I was just using an empty `__init__.py` and then when you import the module you get everything and more.  I suppose it doesn't really matter except that when people are trying to read inline docs or find method names it just makes it so they have more to search through.    Thanks for the comment.